# Turbo C strcpy library function

Tags: c, string, strcpy, turbo-c

I discovered that the strcpy function simply copied one string to anther. For instance, if a program included the following statements:

```
char buffer[10];
----------
strcpy(buffer, "Dante");
```

the string "Dante" would be placed in the array buffer[]. The string would include the terminating null(**\0**), which means that six characters in all would be copied. I'm just wondering **why we can't achieve the same effect more simply by saying?**:

```
buffer = "Dante";
```

If I'm not mistaken, C treats strings far more like arrays than BASIC does.

Comment: please, Please, PLEASE stop using Turbo C. Seriously. There are compilers which actually conform to the standard, can produce 32 bit native executables, and most importantly are **free** -- e.g. MinGW or MSVC++ on Windows, or LLVM or GCC on Unix.

Comment: @Billy ONeal I think you're right. But I'm sorry, it's our school requirement... I have to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because strings aren't a data type in C. "Strings" are `char*`s, so when you try to assign them, you are simply copying the memory address and not the characters into the buffer.

Consider this:

```
char* buffer;

buffer = malloc(20);
buffer = "Dante";
```

Why should it magically place "Dante" into the buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Because an "array" in C is a chunk of memory. There's no pointer to assign to.

---

If you're asking why the *syntax* isn't like that: Well, what would happen if the lengths were different?

Answer (score 3):

Address of array is not changeable. In **other sense** you can consider,

```
char buffer[20];
```

is a **compile time** equivalent of,

```
char* const buffer = (char*)malloc(20);
```

Now, since `buffer` address cannot be changed, one cannot perform operations like:

```
buffer = "Dante"; // error 'buffer' address is not modifiable
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write `buffer`, it is treated as a pointer to the first element of the array. Of course, `*buffer` or `buffer[0]` is the first element. Since `buffer` is just a pointer, you can't assign a whole bunch of data like `"Dante"` to it.

Comment: Not true -- an array is a datatype in C. Do not confuse arrays with pointers -- they are not the same. Just because an array can decay into a pointer to its first element does not mean that the array *is* the pointer to the first element. e.g. `int myArray[42];` does **not** declare a pointer.

Comment: @Billy, I was expecting such a comment. I can't imagine array to be a data type. it's a collection of data. how it can simply be a type? oh, and yes, i know that the pointer and array aren't same.

Comment: Because the standard says so. And because it changes how `sizeof` works -- `sizeof(myArray)` (from above) is `42 * sizeof(int)` -- `sizeof(int *)` is always the size of a pointer. Arrays carry size and dimension information. Pointers do not.

Comment: I know that in C, a string is not a formal data type as it is in some languages. Instead, it is an array of type char.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do `buffer = "Dante"` because there is no "string" data type in C, only arrays.

Now you CAN however do...

```
char buffer[10] = "Dante";
```

but if the length of the string is unknown you can do...

```
char buffer[] = "Dante123456678";
```

but only during initialization, meaning you can't do...

```
char buffer[];

buffer = "Dante";
```

Answer (score 2):

- If `char buffer[128];` was the declaration, then `buffer` refers the first location of the array, so buffer = "Dante" will try assigning the *address of the string* onto the address which is stored in the array. Memory address location in the array are read only and statically assigned when compiled. So you cannot do `buffer = "Dante"` as it attempts to change an address location which points to some other location fixed at compile time. These locations cannot be written.
- If `char *buffer;` was the declaration, then `buffer` is a pointer to a `char` type variable which can point to a starring chunk of memory blocks. So when you do `buffer = "Dante"` the *address of the string* into `buffer`. When *will* show the string when you print it, as it points to a string starting address, which is compiled in and stored in the executable. But this is not a preferred method.
- If you do `char arr[] = "Dante";` the string "Dante" gets stored in the `.text` section where you can write, so `arr[0] = 'K'` something like this , ie modification is possible.
- If you do `char *arr = "Dante";` then the string "Dante" gets stored in the `.rodata` or similar location which is not writeable. This is because string literals are not modifiable as per the standards.